# I want to refresh the checkboxes when I am selecting another item from the dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

Basically I am assigning roles to the users. I want to automatically show the pre-asssigned roles. I am able to render that on the first time, but the checkboxes remains same when value is changed in dropdown:

```
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/UserRoles/myaction",
    data: { "userid": DropDownSelectedVal },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var a = (data[i]);
            $("#" + a).attr('checked', true);
        });
    },

    error: function (error) {
        alert('error; ' + eval(error));
    }

})
```

Comment: Could you provide more code snippets of your html and elaborate what you trying to do.

Comment: @Abdul Basit Rana :debug you jquery code using developer option of browser and tried to find that if your $("#" + a) code is giving the pointer of correct element.Use Consol window of developer option and see each attribute and their value using running $("#" + a) code

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake what else you want??

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui i have tried it .. and yes it is giving everything correctly

Comment: @AbdulBasitRana: when you changed the drop down have you cleared all checkboxes first and then you are trying to select new item on success. Also use prop method in place of attr

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui yes you are right i want to uncheck irrelevant checkboxes when selecting other items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to clear all check boxes using the below code on selection change event of dropdown.

```
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Then run your ajax code for selecting new user roles.

```
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/UserRoles/myaction",
            data: { "userid": DropDownSelectedVal },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    $("#" + val).prop('checked', true);
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }


        })
```

Comment: @AbdulBasitRana : Please mark this as answer if this help you

Answer (score 0):

You should control all checkbox. You can try this.

```
url: "/UserRoles/myaction",
data: { "userid": DropDownSelectedVal },
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {

        var a = (data[i]);
       if(!$("#" + a).is(":checked")) {

        $("#" + a).attr("checked", true);

            }else{
            $("#" + a).attr("checked", false);
             }
    });
},
```

Comment: it is not a solution.. i just wanted to refresh or reset the checkboxes value when selecting next time

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution that I can suggest is to maintain a hidden input to store all your permission that is selected.

Your HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="_hiddenSelectedPermissions" value="2, 1" />
<input class="permissions" type="checkbox" value="1">Default Permission 1
<input class="permissions" type="checkbox" value="2">Default Permission 2
<input class="permissions" type="checkbox" value="3">Permission 3
<input class="permissions" type="checkbox" value="4">Permission 4
<input class="permissions" type="checkbox" value="5">Permission 5
```

Set the hidden control value after ajax results and call below function to reassign all the checked check boxes

```
function refreshSelectedPermissions() {
  $('input:checkbox.permissions').prop('checked', false);
  var selected = $('#_hiddenSelectedPermissions').val().split(",") || [];
  $('input:checkbox.permissions').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if($.inArray(value, selected) === -1){  
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
}
```